# Bringing Hexadecimal from .txt to a array/string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, hex

My problem is that i have a text file that contains this information in hex and was printed by this:

```
fprintf(todos,"ff ff %02x 07 03 24 %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n",id,posl,posh,vell,velh,soma) ;
```

All of the variables are in 'int' format and have decimal values

and this is one example of result

```
0xff 0xff 0x01 0x07 0x03 0x24 0x0c 0x00 0x02 0x01 0x3e
```

And i want to put this sequence into a array/string inside the program.
However, when i try using 'fgets' or 'fgetc' for picking each individual element, it simply won't work because when i try to print it the result is something like

```
' '
```

Is this happening because i am considering hexadecimal numbers to be char? or is there other reason i can't see?

Comment: No sample input or sample output.  This question is very unclear.  You are asking us to read through your code and tell you what's wrong, based on a very confusing description.

Comment: I've edited it in order to make it understandable, if it still continues confusing please let me know!

Comment: Your question is all over the place and difficult to understand. First you said the `printf` was printing blanks for your values. You've since edited the question and now it is even more unclear what you are asking. Are you still talking about the `printf`? Or is it a crash that is the real problem? Or what?? Please simplify your description and clearly state **one specific question**.

Comment: output can be simplified greatly, but looks fine.

Comment: Reading and writing to the file at the same time can be problematic.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: i've simplified it, sorry for the mess.

Comment: Are you saying your text file begins with `'0', 'x', 'f', 'f', ' ', ...` or that that it actually begins with `'\xff', '\xff', '\x1', '\x7', ...`?

Comment: Yes, it begins with '0' 'x' 'f' 'f', and they are all chars, the problem is that in the "0x0c 0x00 0x02 0x01 0x3e" section, all numbers that follow a 0x are int numbers printed using ("%x") in a fprintf

Comment: I think [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might help more

Comment: But when i try 'fscanf' should i consider them chars? Because i tried doing like this before and got no success

Comment: You can parse a string of hex numbers (with `0x` prefix) in a loop using [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: `fscanf()` using modified format string you used in `fprintf()` should be able to read and assign the values to int variables. This should work `fscanf(todos, "0xff 0xff 0x%02x 0x07 0x03 0x24 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x",&id,&posl,&posh,&vell,&velh,&soma);` or `fscanf(todos, "0xff 0xff %04x 0x07 0x03 0x24 %04x %04x %04x %04x %04x",&id,&posl,&posh,&vell,&velh,&soma);`.

Comment: You can even drop the format size `fscanf(todos, "0xff 0xff %x 0x07 0x03 0x24 %x %x %x %x %x",&id,&posl,&posh,&vell,&velh,&soma);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells too much like homework, so I don't want to do too much.

First bit: Simplifying the inputs. This has been deleted from the question, but it is important stuff to know.

```
posl = pos & 0xFF; // using masking to ignore the upper bytes
posh = (pos >> 8) & 0xFF; // using shifting to move the upper byte into
                          // the lower, and then masking
```

Given pos of 42330 (0xA55A)

pos1 becomes `A55A AND 00FF` or `005a`

Pos2 becomes `A55A right shift 8` or `00A5` (possibly `FFA5` if int is 16 bit due to sign extension). `00A5` is then masked just like pos1.

No need for if statements, modulus or any other rigmarole.

Next, if you are going to read and write the same file, you have to watch out for where in the file the file handle is pointing if you want to read the line you just wrote, you will have to [fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek) back to the beginning of the line. That can be tricky without a bunch of extra book-keeping. Have fun!

Assuming you found the line you want to read, [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) will make it easy to recover your data.

```
int count = fscanf(todos, "ff ff %x 07 03 24 %x %x %x %x %x\n",
                       &id, &posl, &posh, &vell, &velh, &soma);
```

The simple approach is to clone your output line and replace the variables with the appropriate format specifier. Every value read needs to go somewhere so you need to provide the address of the variable.

In the provided sample I store the return value of fscanf as count. Count will be set to the number of requested variables successfully read. If count did not read the number of variable asked for, 6 in this case, the line was not successfully parsed.

Puting the data back together is a matter of betting the right bytes in the right places, so we use the left shift operator to undo what we did earlier with the right shift and then mask in the lower byte.

```
pos = posh<<8 | posl;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it actually worked, and i can't believe now that the reason i was stuck with this problem for almost a week now was only because i didn't do a 'rewind()'.
Also thank you for the lesson on masking and shifting, those are things that i didn't know, and will be looking into it for sure!

Comment: Not a problem, @Andretr . I didn't suggest rewind because it is destructive. If you go back to the beginning of the file after every line, you never have more than one line in the file. You're constantly overwriting what you just wrote, and that's rarely what you want in real world file IO.